# How to use telerik ui plug in for side drawer in NativeScript app

Tags: telerik, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm using Telerik UI plugin in my NativeScript app for implementing drawer functionality.I'm following this tutorial for this - https://www.nativescript.org/blog/details/using-cross-platform-native-sidedrawer-component-in-nativescript

Here is my Code-

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import listViewModule = require("nativescript-telerik-ui/listview");
import drawerModule = require("nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer");
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
<drawer:SideDrawer id="drawer1">
   <drawer:SideDrawer.mainContent>

        <!-- Place your page content here -->
        <StackLayout>
        <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"></Label>
        <Button text="TAP" (tap)="onTap()"></Button>
        <Label [text]="message" class="message" textWrap="true"></Label>
        </StackLayout>

       <StackLayout>
        <Button tap="openDrawer" text="ToggleDrawer"/>
       </StackLayout>
   </drawer:SideDrawer.mainContent>

   <drawer:SideDrawer.drawerContent>
     <StackLayout cssClass="drawerContent">
       <StackLayout cssClass="headerContent">
         <Label text="Drawer Header"/>
       </StackLayout>

       <StackLayout cssClass="drawerMenuContent">
         <Label text="Item 1"/>
         <Label text="Item 2"/>
         <Label text="Item 3"/>
         <Label text="Item 4"/>
       </StackLayout>

     </StackLayout>
   </drawer:SideDrawer.drawerContent>
</drawer:SideDrawer>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
    public counter: number = 16;
    public get message(): string {
        if (this.counter > 0) {
            return this.counter + " taps left";
        } else {
            return "Hoorraaay! \nYou are ready to start building!";
        }
    }

    public onTap() {
        this.counter--;
    }
}
```

When I'm running this in my Emulator I'm getting a blank page. I'm using AngularJS2 with typescript & totally new to both these tools. So, can't able to understand what's I'm doing wrong.

Need some Guide.

Answer (score 2):

1. nativescript-telerik-ui\listview and sidedrawer was before 2.0.0-rc.1 so they are currently working on it you can check this link - https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/issues/1#issuecomment-225791969
2. if you are using beta version of angular then check this link to repository -    https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/release/sdkAngular/app/sidedrawer

Comment: Thanks for this info. I tried on your second suggestion. But, seems like there is some issue in that code base & telerik team working on a new release by this month end. `https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/issues/1` . So, planning to wait some more time.